# Can Tridion be used for knowledge management or customer support portals?

Tags: 2013

I just wondered if anyone has customized Tridion to manage their online customer help portal, with help articles, advanced search, dynamic FAQ lists, etc. I feel like it is unlikely, as SDL themselves are using the same knowledge management system as we do (Moxie) to support their customers. Maybe this could get more likely in v2013?

Comment: Generally the "can product X to be used for solution domain Y" question in IT can be answered with a "yes but..." so perhaps you should tell us what features you're hoping to get and what other products you are considering?

Answer (score 4):

Tridion is a very generic content management system which exerts no restrictions on the type of application it can be used for. You can architect Tridion to deliver content to any type of application.

So the simple answer is yes and no.

Tridion can not be used as a customer help portal out of the box, however, if you want to build the yourself, it could be.

The decision you will have to make is, do you want to build a custom portal (factors: features, cost, time etc..) vs. buying an off the shelf product.

Tridion has very powerful APIs, so given the right off the shelf product, Tridion could still be responsible for the content management of articles, FAQs etc...

The features you have described (help articles, advanced search, dynamic FAQ lists, etc) would be relatively easy using a Tridion powered web application. It might get a bit more tricky if you want to run real support tickets.

Answer (score 2):

One of the projects we've worked on in the past sounds pretty similar to what you're looking for.

The customer was using SDL Tridion for their websites / applications and was looking to rebuild their internal help site for the customer support team of this particular client.  Their support team receives a call and they then use the help site to quickly search and answer questions for the customer etc.

Functionality included : search, dynamic faqs, content taxonomies etc etc.

This made sense as we'd built a lot of content, layout and functionality for their websites that we could re use into the internal help sites, if your client is using SDL for other projects, i'd recommend there's a lot to gain from using it to build the help portal.

Comment: What about the Tridion product knowledge center. Is http://docs.sdl.com/ created in SDL Tridion 2013 CMS or is it the new CXM product Knowledge Center

Comment: it is built with Knowledge Center which is great for contextual and collaborative technical documentation, knowledge base articles and more. I would definitely recommend it for customer support portal in terms of self service and interactive documentation, and even more when your products are technical or even complex.

Comment: SDL uses Moxie to offer Knowledgebase features. This suggests to me that SDL Tridion nor CXM Knowledge Center are good for that functionality. http://help.sdl.com/support/index-tab2.html#tabs

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on a Tridion implementation where it was used to provide a customer support portal. Yes, Tridion can be used for customer support portals. Tridion published content to a database and the web application used AJAX and a REST API to serve the content to a call center with about 1,000 employees.

Tridion is a Content Management System that's focused towards web content management. Software always performs best when you use it the way it is meant to be used. So, as a Knowledge Management tool, Tridion may not be great. But if you wanted it to *store and publish* content for a knowledge management tool, then Tridion would do very well.

Especially if the content or knowledge is shared between both internal and external users (i.e. intranet and website), Tridion would be a very powerful tool for your organization.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using atlassian's confluence for knowledge management. pretty quick to setup without too many hassles. SDL tridion is very powerful and does many other things related to WCM and might be an overkill for your requirment.

Comment: My goal was to move CMS and KMS onto one platform for the good of our authors and our customers. This may not be possible/recommended given the comments I've seen here.